# add Alt Attribute to all Images - Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes, alt

How would I be able to loop through all the images, retrieve the image title, then add it to the alt attribute?

```
function addAltAtrr() {
    //get the images
    let grabImage = document.querySelectorAll("img"); 
     
    //loop through all images
    for (let i = 0; i < grabImage.length; i++) {  
        grabImage[i].setAttribute("alt", "test");   
    }

}

addAltAtrr();
```

This currently adds the string "text" as an alt attribute

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: Ok so I've tested the code above on a live site, and it works fine, but if I would like to know how to retrieve the image title, and add it as and alt attribute to all images

Comment: You can use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `alt` and `title` properties, which reflect the attributes of the same names. This is assuming by "title" you mean the `title` attribute, which shows as a hover tooltip. If you mean the file name, you could use the image element's `src`, but you'll probably want to process it, removing the file extension for instance.

Also note that screen readers may speak both `alt` and `title`, which would be redundant if one is based on the other.

```
function addAltAttrs() {
    //get the images
    let images = document.querySelectorAll("img"); 
     
    //loop through all images
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        //add alt text if missing (but title is present)
        if (images[i].title && !images[i].alt) {
            images[i].alt = images[i].title;
        }
    }

}

addAltAttrs();
```

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for, with a thorough explanation.